# Importing CherryPy fails on openshift

Tags: python, python-2.7, openshift, cherrypy

I'm running a cherrypy based app on an openshift gear. Recently I've been getting a "503 service temporarily unavailable" error whenever I try to go to the site. Inspecting the logs, I see I'm getting an ImportError where I try to import CherryPy. This is strange - CherryPy is listed as a dependency in my requirements.txt and used to be imported just fine. I double checked to make sure I'm getting the right path to the openshift activate_this.py and it seems to be correct. I'm not quite sure where to look next; any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

The failed import is at line 14 of app.py:

```
import os
import files


virtenv = os.path.join(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_DIR'], 'virtenv')
virtualenv = os.path.join(virtenv, 'bin', 'activate_this.py')
conf = os.path.join(files.get_root(), "conf", "server.conf")
try:
    execfile(virtualenv, dict(__file__=virtualenv))
    print virtualenv
except IOError:
    pass

import cherrypy
import wsgi


def mount():
    def CORS():
        cherrypy.response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = os.environ['OPENSHIFT_APP_DNS']

    cherrypy.config.update({"tools.staticdir.root": files.get_root()})
    cherrypy.tools.CORS = cherrypy.Tool('before_handler', CORS)
    cherrypy.tree.mount(wsgi.application(), "/", conf)


def start():
    cherrypy.engine.start()


def end():
    cherrypy.engine.exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mount()
    start()
```

**UPDATE**

I eventually saw (when pushing to the openshift repo using git bash CLI) that the dependency installation from requirements.txt was failing with some exceptions I haven't bothered to look into yet. It then goes on to try to install dependencies in setup.py, and that works just fine.

Regarding the port in use issue...I have no idea. I changed my startup from tree.mount and engine.start to quickstart, and everything worked when I pushed to openshift. Just for kicks (and because I need it to run my tests), I switched back to cherrypy.tree.mount, pushed it, and it worked just fine.

Go figure.

Comment: I have always used the setup.py file to define my dependencies.  Have you done a pip freeze to see if cherrypy is actually installed?

Comment: According to the docs at https://developers.openshift.com/languages/python/getting-started.html#step3, requirements.txt should work, and it was definitely working in the past. Maybe that's changed?

Sshing into the app and doing pip freeze didn't show me cherrypy installed, and neither did printing help('modules') from inside app.py. So it seems like either the virtualenv isn't getting started or pip install is either failing or not being run. Unfortunately, I'm fresh out of guesses as to why any of these things might be happening, or how to debug more.

Comment: ssh into your app and type 'source  python/virtenv/venv/bin/activate'. Then do a pip freeze. Is cherrypy installed then?  if not, it is definitely not installed. For kicks try using setup.py.

Comment: Ah, so that's where the virtualenv lives. I made a setup.py and that seems to have fixed the dependency issue. Odd, but thanks! Now cherrypy is trying to start, but says I can't create a socket on port 8080 (which is what the OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_PORT resolves to). After finding https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/port-binding-routing.html, I changed the port I'm starting my app on to 8000, but I'm still getting the "No socket could be created (127.0.0.1, 8080) permission denied" error. Any ideas?

Comment: see my answer below. I hope that helps.  Let me know if you have other questions.

Comment: What is the cherrypy version? Have you locked it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the app.py entry point for Openshift.  Here are several examples on how I start my server using the pyramid framework on Openshift.  I use waitress as the server but I have also used the cherrypy wsgi server.  Just comment out the code you don't want.

**app.py**

```
#Openshift entry point

import os

from pyramid.paster import get_app
from pyramid.paster import get_appsettings


if __name__ == '__main__':
    here = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

    if 'OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME' in os.environ:                                          #are we on OPENSHIFT?
        ip = os.environ['OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_IP']
        port = int(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_PORT'])
        config = os.path.join(here, 'production.ini')
    else:
        ip = '0.0.0.0'                                                              #localhost
        port = 6543
        config = os.path.join(here, 'development.ini')

    app = get_app(config, 'main')                                                   #find 'main' method in __init__.py.  That is our wsgi app
    settings = get_appsettings(config, 'main')                                      #don't really need this but is an example on how to get settings from the '.ini' files

# Waitress (remember to include the waitress server in "install_requires" in the setup.py)
    from waitress import serve
    print("Starting Waitress.")
    serve(app, host=ip, port=port, threads=50)

# Cherrypy server (remember to include the cherrypy server in "install_requires" in the setup.py)
#     from cherrypy import wsgiserver
#     print("Starting Cherrypy Server on http://{0}:{1}".format(ip, port))
#     server = wsgiserver.CherryPyWSGIServer((ip, port), app, server_name='Server')
#     server.start()


#Simple Server
    # from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
    # print("Starting Simple Server on http://{0}:{1}".format(ip, port))
    # server = make_server(ip, port, app)
    # server.serve_forever()

#Running 'production.ini' method manually.  I find this method the least compatible with Openshift since you can't
#easily start/stop/restart your app with the 'rhc' commands. Mabye somebody can suggest a better way :)

# #Don't forget to set the Host IP in 'production.ini'.  Use 8080 for the port for Openshift
# You will need to use the 'pre_build' action hook(pkill python) so it stops the existing running instance of the server on OS
# You also will have to set up another custom action hook so rhc app-restart, stop works.
# See Openshifts Origin User's Guide  ( I have not tried this yet)

#Method #1
    # print('Running pserve production.ini')
    # os.system("pserve production.ini &")

#Method #2
    #import subprocess
    #subprocess.Popen(['pserve', 'production.ini &'])
```